# SQLAlchemy query filter behavior confusing in docs

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am a little confused at how to use multiple filter criteria in a query. Below, the SQLAlchemy documentation states:

**Multiple criteria are joined together by AND:**

```
session.query(MyClass).\
    filter(MyClass.name == 'some name', MyClass.id > 5)
```

Although I do not see "AND" anywhere in that query.

So, I assume the comma is the AND syntax.

What would the syntax for "OR" be?

[link to filter section of documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)

Answer (score 1):

if you scroll a little bit down, you'll see this in the docs:

> Changed in version 0.7.5: Multiple criteria joined by AND.

You perform an `or` using the or_ function.  See below.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import or_
>>> print or_(m.User.first_name == u'jaime', m.User.last_name == u'wyant')
"user".first_name = :first_name_1 OR "user".last_name = :last_name_1
```

Comment: It is quite the confusing statement when they say that same thing right before the example that doesn't match. "Do as I say, not as I do"

Comment: SQLAlchemy can be confounding at times.  Luckily for me, I do fairly basic things.  For the really complex things, the mailing list is where to go.  Mike Bayer does a great job of answering virtually everything.  I think he's a robot.